# Apex Class Controller Not working when trying to set up Lightning component in VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, force.com-sites

I am attempting to insert a lightning component into a visual force page for use on my site. I have the visual force page set up to use the lightning component, and the lightning component is properly connected to its controller. I know the lightning component works because I can drag it into a community portal page and it works perfectly. I have the necessary apex class is in the VF pages Apex Class Access but it is still not working. I don't even get a debug log when I run the page (indicating that the apex class doesn't run). The following is my relevant code:

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="EntireSiteApexClass" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
 
    <div id="lightning" />
 
    <script>
    
       $Lightning.use("diznp123:lightningtest", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:EntireSiteComponent",
              {},
              "lightning",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
                
       });  
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Lightning App**

```
<aura:application  access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
   <c:EntireSiteComponent /> 
</aura:application>
```

**Entire Site Component**

```
<aura:component controller="diznp123.EntireSiteApexClass" access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:attribute name="ScreenCounter" type="Integer" default="1" />
    
   <!-- Login Component --> 
  <aura:attribute name="Username" type="String"/>
   <aura:attribute name="Password" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Result" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
      <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ScreenCounter == 1}">
     <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:42rem;width:89.7rem;padding:2rem">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center"> 
          <table>
           <tr>
               <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                   <td><lightning:input aura:id="usernameId" value="{!v.Username}" minlength="0" maxlength="18" label="Username"></lightning:input></td>
                   </lightning:layoutItem>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                   <td><lightning:input aura:id="passwordId" type="password" value="{!v.Password}" minlength="0" maxlength="18" label="Password"></lightning:input></td>
           </lightning:layoutItem>
           </tr>
                  <div class="slds-m-vertical--medium">
              <tr>
             <div >
             <td><lightning:button label="Login to Payment Portal" onclick="{!c.portalLogin}"  variant="brand"></lightning:button></td>
                  </div> 
                  </tr>
                      <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                      <tr><td><lightning:button label="Forget your Password?" variant="base" onclick="{!c.forgotPassword}" disabled="true"></lightning:button></td></tr>
                      
                      </lightning:layoutItem>
                  </div>
              </table>
           
          
        </lightning:layout>
         <aura:if isTrue="{!not(v.Result)}">
             <p>Incorrect Password {!v.url}</p>
         </aura:if>
        
        
    </div>
```

**Entire Site Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class EntireSiteApexClass {
 
    /////////// Login Controller ////////////
    public String Resource { get; set; }
    public String username {get;set;}
    public String password {get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean loginFunction(){
     
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your Lightning App markup is incorrect. It should be:

```
<aura:application  access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
   <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:EntireSiteComponent" /> 
</aura:application>
```

Everything else appears to be correct.

Comment: Hello, I've changed what you said and it still doesn't seem to connect to the apex class, is there anything else you could suggest?